# Obtener el file de un input type file

Tags: javascript, c#, html, jquery, asp.net-mvc-5

Hola quiero obtener **el archivo** de un input file. No quiero su nombre , ni sus propiedades si no el archivo como tal, para después subirlo a un repositorio en mi servidor. Pero creo que estoy haciendo algo mal con mi **Js**. Agradecería infinitamente su ayuda.

```js
    function tryme() {

        var file = $('#fileinput').prop("files")[0];

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "json",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            url: '@Url.Action("CreateRequest", "Home")',
            data: "{'File':'" + file + "'}",
            success: function (response) {
                alert("at least Ajax looks fine");
            },
            Error: function (textMsg) {

                alert("something got wrong");
            }
        });
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <input type="file" id="fileinput"   />
<input type="submit"  onclick="tryme()" value="click" />

</body>
</html>
```

Esta bastante simple, me tira **undefinded** o tambien **[object FileList]**.
Quisiera saber ¿si ese **[object FileList]** puedo ocuparlo para subirlo a la base de datos?

```js
   
    public JsonResult  CreateRequest(FileInfo format )
    {

        string cs = "Data Source=DMX87025;Initial Catalog=DB_PCC;Integrated Security=True";
        string sql = "INSERT INTO [DB_PCC].[dbo].[Testsoru]" +
            "([Format])" +
            "VALUES" +
            "(@Format)";

        

        using (SqlConnection con= new SqlConnection(cs) ) {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql,con);
            
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@Format", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = format;

            con.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con.Close();
        }

       
        return Json(new { success = true, message = "Success:D" }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);


        // End CreateRequest
    }
```

Comment: **.prop('files')** te devolverá un arreglo por tanto tienes que acceder al archivo a traves de un indice es decir .prop("files")[0].

Comment: Para enviarlo en un ajax intenta usando un FormData

Comment: El alert no es un método de debugging en javascript, deberías usar el console.log(). Si lo hubieras usado te hubieses dado cuenta de que era un array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Asumo que tienes un botón de subir cuyo id es upload_button y a partir de ahi armo el siguiente ejemplo, este código es del lado del cliente, del lado del servidor me imagino que no tienes problema tratando con los archivos subidos. **:)**

```
$('#upload_button').on('click', function(){
    //Obtengo el fichero que va a ser subido
    var dato_archivo = $('#fileinput').prop("files")[0];
    //Creo un dato de formulario para pasarlo en el ajax
    var form_data = new FormData();
    //Añado los datos del fichero que voy a subir
    //En el lado del servidor puede obtener el archivo a traves de $_FILES["file"]
    form_data.append("file", dato_archivo);
    //Realizo el ajax
    $.ajax({
        //La url que se encargara de procesar la subida del archivo
        url: 'tu_pagina.php',
        //El tipo de respuesta que me devolverá la página en mi caso será un texto indicando el estado de la subida
        dataType: 'text',
        processData: false,
        //El dato pasado a la solicitud
        data: form_data,
        //El tipo que será la solicitud
        type: 'post',
        //Si la operación tiene éxito...
        success: function(respuesta){
           alert(respuesta);
        },
        //Si la operación tiene un error
        error: function(){
            alert("Ha ocurrido un error");
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Hola @Dariel Ramos Díaz de Villegas si de hecho si tengo una duda con respecto al lado del servidor, primero lo estoy manejando en **C#** la cuestión es el tipo de dato con el cual puedo manejar este objeto. ¿Me explico? es decir en un método al cual le voy a estar pasando estos datos en específico ... `public void metodox(object form_data ???)` . Muchas grácias pro tu tiempo btw :D

Comment: Con que estas programando tu lado del servidor, con WebForms, ASP.NET MVC, o que?

Comment: Con ASP.NET Y con AJAX

Comment: Pon tu codigo C# donde procesas lo enviado por el cliente

Comment: Listo @Dariel Ramos Díaz de Villegas

Comment: En el código nuevo que anexastes no hay nada que indique que recives la información pasada por el ajax, solamente es una función donde devuelves un Json luego de ejecutar determinada consulta de sql. Si puede pon más código porque ese no brinda información suficiente

Comment: Listo disculpa es que era una función un poco más larga pero lo que me interesa esta ahí@Dariel Ramos Díaz de Villegas